# Apache NIFI: Unable to write flow content

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I have a csv file that I ingested to NiFi using GetFile Processor, then used ConvertRecord Processor without any issue, when I dragged the ExecuteStreamCommand to the canvas to run a python script I run to some issues to write the fileflow.

This is the configuration I used:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLLm2.png)

The python script:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sys
from io import StringIO

try:

    # Read input data from the stdin:
    path_file = sys.stdin.read()
    input_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(path_file))

    # Fill missing values with column means
    input_df.dropna(inplace=True)

    # Write the processed data to the stdout:
    sys.stdout.write(input_df.to_csv(path_file, index=False))

except Exception as e:
    sys.stderr.write("An error occurred: {}".format(str(e)))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mECUA.png)

As you can see in the image, the flow is read but unable to write to the next processor, and I keep getting the error:

> Unable to write flowfile content to content repository container default due to archive file size constraints; waiting for archive cleanup. Total number of files currently archived = 13

For your information, I have already tried disabling the **nifi.flow.configuration.archive.enabled=false**
and resized the max storage size to 10 GB but to no avail, I keep having the same error.

What should I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As a heads-up, I found the cause of my problem.
In the python script :

```
    # Write the processed data to the stdout:
    sys.stdout.write(input_df.to_csv(path_file, index=False))
```

the path_file should be removed and this command instead:

```
    sys.stdout.write(input_df.to_csv(index=False))
```